# LARAVEL - Form validation return back to view instead of returning JSON?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't remember this is always been so freakin' hard to do in Laravel, but how to return back to form page `blade.php` instead of displaying the errors as JSON object on the browser?

Controller

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('view.to.form');
}

public function store(CreateModelRequest $request)
{
    Model::create($request->validated());
}
```

// CreateModelRequest

```php
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    return back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

> **I've tried countless other "solutions" as well, but no matter what,**
>   **the failed form request return raw JSON to the browser:**

```
{
message: 'The given data was invalid',
errors: {
    first_name: ['The first name field is required.'],
    last_name: ['The last name field is required.'],
    email: ['The email field is required.'],
},
}
}
```

Comment: How are you submitting this form? the form request only returns JSON if the request excepts JSON, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L255), otherwise it will return back to the previous page, in your case the  create form and flash the validation errors to the session.

Comment: @Remul traditional submit event with zero JS

Comment: Check your headers, you are providing information that makes Laravel think that you want a JSON response.

Comment: @Remul No, I was thinking the same but unfortunately, I found nothing JSON related

Comment: Then I would add a `dd()` for `$request->expectsJson()` and see if it returns true or false.

Comment: @Remul I did that. It's false

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one way to return back to the form but damn this is awful:

```php
// Controller's store method
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    // rules
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```

I'd like to extract that code into `Request` class but apparently we can't return a view and therefore we can't use them outside of API endpoints. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: the code sample you provided is useful for API based or AJAX-based validation. To use it with the blade/server-side request. Just use `$this->validate()` method from Controller that should do the trick. There is `$errors` variable available in the blade to get all of your validation error.

Comment: Maybe you were trying to do something that isn't built in ... but it doesn't look like it. 
 [There is almost nothing to validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation)!

Comment: @AnujShrestha the same issue remains. Validation errors are returned as JSON directly to the browser

Comment: @CecilyMiller show how you submit the form. It only returns JSON if you are sending `Accept: application/json` on the header. I don't think this is any laravel issue.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Traditional blade form which is submitted by clicking `button` with `type="submit"` - Here are the sent headers: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9` and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`